# Pass a function to a web worker that uses a webpack imported class

Tags: javascript, webpack, import, module, web-worker

I want to pass a simple function to a web worker, rather than writing it directly in the web worker. I know this isn't directly possible, but that you can "work around" this in many cases by calling `toString()` on your function and calling `eval` on that string, once it's in the worker.

The caveat that I haven't seen addressed elsewhere is that this function uses a class imported from another module. (I am using webpack.)

Take this function: `() => new MyClass();`

Calling `toString()` on it gives this:

```
() => {
  return new _MyClass__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__["MyClass"]();
}
```

That makes sense, as `MyClass` is imported from another module. The problem is that calling `eval` on this in the worker gives an error:

> ReferenceError: _MyClass__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__ is not defined

Again, that makes sense, because the class wasn't imported in the worker's module. But is there any way I can work around this? The class referenced by the function won't be known at the time that the worker is written.

Unsurprisingly, I get this result whether using worker-loader or creating the worker with an object URL like this:

```
new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([functionString])));
```

I've tried using dynamic imports inside the function I pass into the worker, but this still fails as seemingly the worker doesn't expect to be doing dynamic import:

```
() => {
  return import ('./MyClass')
    .then(module => new module.MyClass());
}
```

> ReferenceError: __webpack_require__ is not defined

Is there any clever way to work around this, or should I give up and expect to write a different worker for every class I want to instantiate?

Comment: I tried serializing the class itself to pass to the worker, which sort-of works, except that this class extends another class, but the "extends" writes out an imported module name, whereas the class name itself is as per the original.

`class MyBaseClass {
  constructor() {
    this.something = [];
  } 
  ...
}`

 doesn't directly relate to 

`class MyInstanceClass extends my_package__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["MyBaseClass"] {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.somethingElse = [];
  }
  ...
}`

Comment: If I try to "force" __webpack_require__ to be defined in my worker by including a dynamic import statement, I instead get `__webpack_require__.e is not a function`

Comment: I tried using worker-plugin instead of worker-loader, but am currently encountering an error using that with dynamic import: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/worker-plugin/issues/43

Comment: The combination of createObjectURL and dynamic imports also doesn't work for me, as \_\_webpack_require__ isn't defined. I can't "force" it to be, as webpack isn't run on the worker content on its own.

Comment: I bypassed the first issue with using worker-plugin with dynamic imports, but import() in the worker expects the file to be named 2.chunk.worker.js, whereas the actual bundle is just named 2.chunk.js.

This can hopefully be worked around if this issue is resolved: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/worker-plugin/issues/19

Comment: Using either worker-loader or worker-plugin with dynamic imports might work if you configure your webpack output filenames to exactly match what either of those plugins produce. But that's far too brittle a solution for my liking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that this can't be done in a robust and non-hacky manner, though I'm happy to be proven wrong still.

I'll use a different worker for each class I want to instantiate, at least for now.